# How to recover a truecrypt container from a corrupt NTFS drive

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, hard-drive-recovery

On my external HDD which is formatted in NTFS I have a truecrypt container. I plugged my drive in today and windows gave me an error that I need to format the disk. How would I go about recovering my trucrypt container from the external drive. I have tried various data recovery programs but non of them support files without an extension (such as my trucrypt container)..

Any advice in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use TestDisk and attempt to repair the partition table. If that fails, use the "list files" command and copy the TrueCrypt container out.